# Is Lockitron a fake?

Tags: consumer-products, marketing

There's a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D1L3o88GKew) going around which proportedly is to sell a product called Lockitron.

To summarise the video, Lockitron is a wifi-enabled, deadlock motivator. You can lock and unlock your door remotely using the internet. Or you can use bluetooth within a certain range.

[image: Lockitron]

It looks awesome. And totally legit. Amazing, but believeable.

But then I saw [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TOKT5ypDo3Q). This is the "new lockitron video". In this one they control lockitron with:

- Bananas, by playing a song on them.
- A magic wand
- And mind control

That just seems over the top. Is Lockitron a legitimate product? Could you really control it using the above?

Comment: explain how I could unlock my house door over the internet, which requires a physical key which I keep in my pocket? Were this possible, ALL locks would be useless, and I'd no doubt have heard from my home insurance company by now about hiring a security firm to watch my house 24/7.

Comment: @jwenting: Look at the picture. It is a device that sits over your lock (on the inside), and turns the knob when given a remote signal. It doesn't magically open any door.

Comment: @Oddthinking Maybe it is magical... in the second video they use a magic wand...

Comment: It is relatively simple - but from a security perspective using bluetooth is an ..interesting.. choice. As a gadget I like it - but would I ever use it? Not a chance!

Comment: Of course it all this relies on having that kind of door with a knob that turns

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The question boils down to: Given we have an electronic device that can be triggered remotely (to lock or unlock a door), is it possible to produce a hardware-based solution that can trigger it by:

1. touching bananas connected to hardware?
2. pushing buttons on a wireless device in the shape of a wand?
3. detecting when you raise your eyebrows, using a device that sits on your head?

The answers are:

1. [Yes](http://hackaday.com/2012/05/17/bananaphone-lets-you-use-fruit-and-other-things-as-switches/)
2. [Yes](http://hackaday.com/2009/05/17/magic-wands-for-disney/)
3. [Yes](http://emotiv.com/)

Comment: For the banana you may want to refer to (the amazing) [MaKey MaKey](http://www.makeymakey.com/).

Comment: This appears to be the exact wand in the video: http://www.thinkgeek.com/product/cf9b/  As you can see, it's clearly designed to control electronic devices.

Answer (score 4):

Lockitron has an interesting story, I was following them quite for a while (mostly on hacker news discussions)

They approached kickstarter and were rejected, created their own crowd-sourcing application, and open sourced it, and managed to get a very nice level of orders.

More on this can be found here: http://techcrunch.com/2012/10/07/the-story-of-lockitron-crowdfunding-without-kickstarter/

All this positive media coverage, and peer reviews, adds to my confidence in their legitimacy.
It still doesn't prove anything, but I thought you will benefit from knowing they are quite famous now along the entrepreneurial community (e.g. not being an unknown / questionable company is certainly helping me when deciding if to trust a company or not)